# Get php url variable for use in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Okay so I have an html5 audio player that i built with jquery however i need to get the track url from the variable in the url with a get request so that it can then be used in the jquery script. Not sure how to do it. I have the jquery in a seperate file to the markup for easy embedding for users. The url will look like www.mysite.co.uk/player/player.html?url=testing123.mp3.

I can easily get the variable for use in the markup to show the name of the artist etc with PHP but not sure how to do it for the jquery script. I have had a look around but no luck.

Heres the relevent jquery

```
song = new Audio('THIS IS WHERE THE GET VARIABLE NEEDS TO BE');
```

I shouldnt think anymore code is needed but if it is just ask.

head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php $url = $_GET['url']; ?> 

<script> // Before jQuery
    var song = new Audio(`<?php echo($url); ?>`);
</script>`
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newbornsounds.co.uk/player/src/js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newbornsounds.co.uk/player/src/js/html5slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Heres the relevent jquery` YMMD. :)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk YMMD = You made my day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url']; // Avoid this way! Need to be as safe as possible.
?>

[...]

<head>
    [...]

    <script> // Before jQuery
        var song = new Audio(`<?php echo($url); ?>`);
    </script>`

    [...]
</head>
```

And remove song from your `.js`

Comment: @JacobWindsor If url is `testing123.mp3` you need to have this file inside the rrot of your website (`http://mydomain.com/testing123.mp3`)

Comment: I do here is one of the tracks on the current site, it will jst play through the usual html player http://newbornsounds.co.uk/uploads/19c9aa51c821952c81be46ca9b2e9056.mp3

Comment: When i reference that same track with the new player nothing happens. I have tried going down all the directories as well with ../ but that just makes the page refresh on play

Comment: @JacobWindsor so, your url need to be `uploads/19c9aa51c821952c81be46ca9b2e9056.mp3` or, `19c9aa51c821952c81be46ca9b2e9056.mp3` with `uploads` already included on `Audio`: `song = new Audio('/uploads/<?php echo($url); ?>');`

Comment: Yes, i forgot to say in the database it already contains ../uploads

Comment: Ok, I have found your problem. You can't add PHP code inside a `.js` file (`http://newbornsounds.co.uk/player/src/js/js.js`)

Comment: I thought that might have been the problem so that is why i asked for a jquery solution

Comment: @JacobWindsor `i need to get the track url from the variable in the url with a get request so that it can then be used in the jquery script.` My approach do what you want, but outside `.js` files.

Comment: Yes i know it does. I need it to be in the .js though for easy embedding

Comment: I have done exactly what you said but the page just refreshes. It's strange. Ill add that part of my head to my question